# Export and save excel in a directory using maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using `maatwebsite (laravel)` to write customer data into existing excel file and export dynamically from database and my code is working fine.

**I am following below link:**

[maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export)

Now I want as excel file will download that should be save in any directory like `/uploads/customers/text.xlsx`

**Edit: See my code:**

```
try {
    Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)->load('/public/uploads/new.xlsx', function($reader) {
    $reader->sheet('sheetname',function($sheet)
    {  
      $sheet->appendRow('test','test', 'test');
    });
 }, 'UTF-8')->export('xlsx');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage().$ex->getLine();
    return response(Helpers::makeDefaultErrorAjaxResponse());
}
```

How can I do that using the maatwebsite function, I am not getting any function for doing this?

Comment: have you tried Excel::create(/uploads/path/'Filename'); ?

Comment: Actually I am writing data in the existing excel sheet.

Comment: I am using  Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)->load('path for file', function($reader){}

Comment: @Rodrane: Check I have updated my question now with code snip.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @RaghbendraNayak?

Answer (score 11):

In Laravel Excel (Maatwebsite Excel 3) you use `store` method on `Excel` facade (`Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel`):

```
Excel::store(new YourExport(), 'customers/fileName.xlsx', 'local');
```

The third parameter is a filesystem defined in `config/filesystems.php` (it's optional). If the location where you want to store those Excel files is outside the default `local` and `public` filesystems, you can add it to the config file:

```
'customer_uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/uploads/customers/',
],
```

And then save your Excel files with the thrid parameter set to that new filesystem:

```
Excel::store(new YourExport(), 'fileName.xlsx', 'customer_uploads');
```

Read more here: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/store.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->save` function to save the generated file to a folder on server.
For more details look at https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/export/store#docs